# How to represent an ordered recursive relationship in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, laravel-5

### Schema

I have the following database schema:

```
=== modules ===
id: PK
name: String
current_revision: FK to revisions.id

=== revisions ===
id: PK
module_id: unsigned int, indexed, FK to modules.id
parent_revision: unsigned int, nullable, indexed, FK to revisions.id
content: string
```

### Example Data

Example data

**modules:**

```
(1, "Maths, 3)
(2, "Computing", 5)
```

**revisions:**

```
(1, 1, null, "Maths - v1")
(2, 1, 1, "Maths- v2")
(3, 1, 2, "Maths - v3")
(4, 2, null, "Computing - v1")
(5, 2, 4, "Computing - v2")
```

### Explanation

As you can see, the `parent_revision` relates to the previous version of that module or `null` if it's the first version for the module.

The `current_revision` relates to the latest version for the category

### What I want?

I wish to represent this relationship as a model in Laravel.
I managed to make a start:

```
class Module extends Model
{
    public function currentRevision()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Revision::class, 'current_revision_id');
    }

    public function revisions()
    {
       /* Help! (I wish to return all the revisions for this module in
       order, starting from the current_revision. e.g. for the "Maths" 
       module it should return the revisions with IDs: [3, 2, 1] and               
       for the "Computing" module it should return: [4, 3]. Order 
       MATTERS!)*/
    }
}
```

-

```
class Revision extends Model
{
    public function module()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Module::class);
    }

    public function nextRevision()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Revision::class, 'parent_revision');
    }

    public function previousRevision()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Revision::class, 'parent_revision');
    }

    public function previousRevisions()
    {
        // TODO: return ALL previous revisions
    }
}
```

I wish to find an *efficient* way to create the `revisions()` method for the `Module` model. How can I do this?

NOTE: I don't mind if you suggest schema changes, provided it is better than what I have currently!

Comment: Does your revision need a parent_revision?  If you just have a module_id and a timestamp to order it by, it could be a lot easier.  It might be worth looking into the `revisionable` package or at least seeing how they do it because it's worked quite well for me in the past.

Comment: @user3158900 What is the `revisionable` package? Also I have tried the timestamp method, but in rare cases, new revisions may be added at the exact second and laravel doesn't store milliseconds or nanoseconds (unlikely I know)! Also in the future this may expand to a tree, where multiple revisions may have the same parent.

Comment: It's a package that handles revisions for you by simply adding a trait to your models which should store revisions.  If you are worried about miliseconds though, it would not fix that.

Comment: Is it this: https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have been more clear about the package itself.  That's the one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether we have a straight line of descent (eg. `revision #1 -> revision #2 -> revision #3 -> ...`) or something that looks like this:

```
Revision #1
 |  |
 |  +- Revision #2
 |      |
 |      +- Revision #4
 |
 +- Revision #3
 |
 ...
```

If it's the simple straight line, then @user3158900's suggestion is probably the simplest.

If it's a branching tree of revisions, then it becomes trickier. For the simple parent - child relationships, you can set them up like this in your model:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Revision::class, 'parent_revision');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Revision::class, 'parent_revision');
}
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
$rev = Revision::find(42);

foreach ($rev->children as $child) {
    // do something with the children
}

$parent = $rev->parent;

// do something with the parent
```

Note that the `children` relationship will be direct descendants only - eg. the direct children of the revision, no grandchildren ,great-grandchildren, etc. To get to those ancestors, you'll need to recurse through the relationships on the children. For example,

```
$rev = Revision::find(42);

foreach ($rev->children as $child) {
    // display the child content
    echo $child->content;

    // display the grandchildren's content
    foreach ($child->children as $grandchild) {
        echo $grandchild->content;
    }
}
```

To truly do this is an efficient way, you'll probably want to write a recursive function.